# How to add filters (server-side) with GridJS

Tags: javascript, html-table, gridjs

I want to know, how I can add filters in GridJS to filter data from the **server**, I have a dropdown list of filters above the table. I want that when someone clicks on a particular filter the table should be re-rendered with the filter.

How can I implement this?

[image]

Comment: the highlighted element says "sort by", are you sure it is a filter?

Comment: @GrafiCode You can say it "sort by" or "filter", The table contains a list of invoices and I want to filter or sort them by "today", "yesterday", "this month" etc.